# HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, eclipselink

I went back to programming my old program https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services. I've updated Spring Boot from version 15.6 to version 2.0.0. I have encountered many problems with compilation, but I can not deal with one. Well, during compilation, he throws me in the console

```
2018-03-18 21:54:53.339 ERROR 3220 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
2018-03-18 21:54:55.392  INFO 3220 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'unit'
2018-03-18 21:54:56.698  INFO 3220 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'unit'
2018-03-18 21:54:56.778 ERROR 3220 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
2018-03-18 21:54:56.782 ERROR 3220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file [C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\web\out\production\classes\com\web\web\security\service\impl\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#65d6e77b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#65d6e77b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
2018-03-18 21:54:56.821  WARN 3220 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

I've never had such a mistake. I do not know what it means completely. My properties for the base look like this

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql:database
    username: root
    password: root
    schema: classpath:/db/init/schema.sql
```

I do not know how to deal with this error. I've been programming quite a long time, but for the first time I'm meeting the concept of `hikari`. I'm using a Tomcat(in Spring Boot) server and a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Shouldn't your url look something like jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/db

Comment: No. https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html In addition, it worked before the Spring Boot version changed.

Comment: OK. One possibility is that the the config variables aren't being picked.

Comment: This is not the current version of the program, but very similar
 https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/src/main/resources/application-dev.yml. I only have this configuration for the database.
 Can I somehow configure these Hikari? I never heard about it.

Comment: Just drop the `driver-class-name` property. Spring Boot will determine the driver class from the URL alone.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue in another context.
From the [79. Data Access - Configure a Custom DataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-a-datasource)

> if you happen to have Hikari on the classpath, this basic setup does not work, because Hikari has no url property (but does have a jdbcUrl property)

Hikari is the default pool in spring boot 2.

so you can replace the config 
`url: jdbc:postgresql:database` -> `jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql:database`

or you can keep the config but you need to define another Bean to handle the mapping (aliases)

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Solved the issue for me, i have 2 datasource and in my properties i just replaced like app.datasource1.url to app.datasource1.jdbc-url

Comment: Also you may have a look here to see a different approach creating the datasource: https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp#1-creating-a-datasource

Answer (score 30):

Either remove `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property or rename the `spring.datasource.url` property to `spring.datasource.jdbc-url`.

This is reported in your error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName

First option looks cleaner and Spring Boot will figure out the default driver class name based on the `spring.datasource.url` property value (see `org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver` class if you want to debug this).

Answer (score 2):

I've also faced the same issue while configuring two database and below solution resolved my issue.
Solution: rename the `spring.datasource.url` property to `spring.datasource.jdbc-url`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).