# Spring Boot defining two datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Java 4 and Spring Boot 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT application.

It needs to access two separate datasources. I am also using Spring jdbc to query the databases.

I have tried an implementation (see below), but I get errors.

I have the following:

**application.properties**

```
# pims datasource
spring.datasource1.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pims
spring.datasource1.username=postgres
spring.datasource1.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
# approval datasource
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/approval
spring.datasource2.username=postgres
spring.datasource2.password=
```

and

**MultipleDBConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nexct")
public class MultipleDBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "datasource1")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource1")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource1(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "datasource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource2")
    public DataSource dataSource2(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Then in the DAO, I define the jdbcTemplate.

**CompanyContactDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class CompanyContactDAOImpl implements CompanyContactDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource1") // pims datasource
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

**ApprovalRequestDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class ApprovalRequestDAOImpl implements ApprovalRequestDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource2") // approval datasource
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Now when I start Spring Boot, I get the following error:

> Could not autowire. Qualified bean must be of 'JdbcTemplate' type.

and

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'approvalRequestDAOImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("datasource2")}

and

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'approvalRequestDAOImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("datasource2")}
> at
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean
> of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("datasource2")}

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/30344608/6270888

Comment: Please read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is related to something else. Your JdbcTemplates *require* a datasource, they're not datasources by themselves. Create a JdbcTemplate and inject the datasource rather than setting the qualifiers on the JdbcTemplates, for instance:

```
@Repository
public class ApprovalRequestDAOImpl implements ApprovalRequestDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public ApprovalRequestDAOImple(@Qualifier("datasource2") DataSource ds) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#JdbcTemplate-javax.sql.DataSource-)

Comment: thank you, that fixed my issue, I get no errors now in start up. I am just going to test it.

Comment: I just get the following error now, which I think is related to my properties file: `HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.`.  I am just looking to fix it

Comment: All works now, thank you.  Fix for `HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352800/hikaripool-1-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname